# call not redirect through .htaccess file

Tags: php

I have htaccess file having the following code, i just want to redirect calls directly to rest(folder)/api(php file)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?function=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Call not redirected, whats the problem ??

Comment: u  mean,  it must be removed ???

Comment: i have a folder , named as rest i n which all php files are there

Comment: problem is, it do not show 404, just responding me with some html code